# How to position an image in HTML & CSS with DIV or other

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

**Hello**, I've been looking for different tutorials, I've tried different things, and so far nothing has worked so I'm here to know if someone could either help me on this test project (in order to learn) or redirect me to a tutorial I'm explaining my concern :

I would like to position my images (currently in this state: https://prnt.sc/11ojid4 by positioning them this way: https://prnt.sc/11ojiuk)
**So I'd like to position them this way:**
2 images and then: 3 images underneath that will be centered like on the picture
and below these 3 images add the last 3
If it's not clear tell me I can explain, if not on the screen you can look at it's pretty explicit but as I said I can explain

**Currently my code looks like this:** (Putting my code back before touching the images in the css) :

```
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400);


* {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #3e3e3e;
}

header {
    background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.99)!important;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.9;
}


.home, .forums, .store {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.home-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}



.forums-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;

}


.store-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}


.register {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.register-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;

}

.login {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.login-a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}


.login-register {
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
}

img {
    width: 256px;
    height: 50px;
}

.header-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px; 
    width: 192px;
    height: 50px;
}



/* Ne pas faire attention je test un effet shine sur mes boutons */
.home-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
  }
  
  .store-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
  }
  
  .forums-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
  }
  
  .login-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
  }

  .register-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
  }
  

  .features {
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #3e3e3e;

}

.purchase {
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #3e3e3e;

}


.kurium__title {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #DDDDDD;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-left: 600px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.kurium__second__title {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: "Nunito";
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;

}

  .features__title {
      padding-top: 20px;
      display: block;
      padding-right: 140px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Nunito';
      font-size: 21px;
      color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );

  }

  .purchase__title {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-size: 21px;
    color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
  }

  .media__title {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-size: 21px;
    color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
  }


  footer {
      text-align: center;
      color:  rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: 'Nunito';
      font-size: 17px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      padding-right: 120px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
      background-color: rgba(34, 33, 33, 0.1)!important;
  }

  .image__feature {
  }


**And for my HTML file here it is:**

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <link rel="icon" type="img/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Home | Kurium v4.5</title>

</head> 

<body>

    <header>
        <div style="display: flex;">
        
            <div style="width: 100%;">
        <ul class="kurium-button">
            <img class="header-logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Kurium Header Logo">
    
            <button class="home"><a class="home-a" href="https://google.fr/">Home</a> </button>
            <button class="forums"><a class="forums-a" href="https://google.fr/">Forums</a> </button>
            <button class="store"><a class="store-a" href="https://google.fr/">Store</a> </button>
        </ul>
    </div>
        
        <div style="width: 10%;">
            <ul class="login-register">
            <!-- A remplacer par : Flexbox -->
            <li class="register" style="float:right"><a class="login-a" href="register.html">Login</a></li></button>
            <li class="login" style="float:right"><a class="register-a" href="login.html">Register</a></li></button>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
        </header>
          <div class="title__wrapper"></div>
            <h1 class="kurium__title">Kurium.</h1>
            <h1 class="kurium__second__title">  Like steroids for Minecraft</h1>
          </div>

        <h1 class="features__title">Features</h1>
          <div class="features">
            <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>

        <h1 class="purchase__title">Purchase</h1>
          <div class="purchase">
            <img class="image__purchase" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__purchase" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>


        <h1 class="media__title">Media</h1>
          <div class="media">
            <img class="image__media" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__media" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__media" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__media" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__media" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <img class="image__media" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>


<!--  Sidebar (Right side in the center) 
            <h1 class="social">Follow US !</h1>
        <div class="follow_us">
            <img class="image_social" src="img/twitter.svg">
            <img class="image_social" src="img/instagram.svg">
            <img class="image_social" src="img/facebook.svg">
            <img class="image_social" src="img/youtube.svg">
            <img class="image_social" src="img/tiktok.svg">
        </div>
-->

        <footer>
            Copyright by Kurium 2017 - 2021
        </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

I really hope that someone will be able to help me because for more than a week I have the brain which burns, the tutorials in French on flexbox are incomprehensible, therefore if someone has the solution, could explain me a little more in details all that I am taker/if you have tutorials on flexbox (preferably in French, but if it is well explained in English that will be fine) thank you in advance for the help that the community is going to bring to me by hoping that soon it will be my turn to bring some x)

Comment: are you using Twitter bootstrap? Would make things a whole lot easier: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/ . If you scroll down to Auto-layout columns, you can see what you are trying to achieve is very similar

Comment: I don't use it because I'm still a beginner, and I prefer to learn html and css in vanilla

Comment: its better to first vanilla HTML and CSS, once you get a good understanding of how things work, then you can migrate to any other framework like bootstrap or material UI etc

Comment: basically, you would create 3 rows, and in each row, you create 2, 3, and 3 items respectively. Much like what Aqib did but personally, I would put the images inside divs as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come across a solution using flexbox which is responsive too,
Firstly in your HTML file, i have added some extra div's and stored images as a set of 2, 3 and 3

```
   <div class="features">
        <div class="features-row-1">
          <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        </div>
        <div class="features-row-1">
          <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        </div>
        <div class="features-row-1">
          <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          <img class="image__feature" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Added container width of 70vw for responsiveness

```
 .features {
     /* setting container width responsive */
    width: 70vw; 
     background-color: #3e3e3e;
 }
```

setting flexbox properties for the each features-row-1 div

```
  .features-row-1{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
}
```

defining width and height in % of the 70vw as defined in features div

```
.image__feature {
     width: 20%;
     height: 30%;
     margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
   }
```

For desired output kindly see my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Aqib_2000/pen/wvgEdKa)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations they were clear I thank you and for the code, it is functional I will readjust it because there are concerns (on my side not yours in fact what you have done is very well centered) - so I will readjust / and test things against the css that you sent me and html I thank you again for the explanations, and help your response has helped me greatly